# ArcGIS frequency analysis tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, frequency

Will the ArcGIS frequency analysis tool work on a shapefile's attribute table or does it only work on a discrete/standalone  table loaded in a mapping session?

Have loaded a geolocated address book into map and am trying to get a count by zip code (one to many), so I might join count to zip code shapefile and symbolize by "quantity".

Comment: Have you already tried using the frequency analysis tool on your shapefile? If so, what errors are you receiving? I believe that there should be no problems using a shapefile  for that analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get a count of ZIP codes, you can right click your field and summarize. That will return a table of ZIP codes and the number of times they appear.

Comment: Won't that just be a histogram versus a table that can be loaded onto map session and used for join?

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of statistics. Summarize returns an output table.